# GAE authenticated user on server-side but not on client-side

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-authentication

I have a GAE Java web application, i authenticate a user with the Google Account and displaing the Admin page. In the other side I in the admin page I have some authenticated functions in JS communicating with a google endpoint backend.
The problem is: my user is authenticated on server-side (it load the restricted page on the browser) but isn't on the JS client-side (the auth restricted function doesn't authenticate him). Is there a mean to do the authentication done on server side working on the client side (no need to ask credential again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do both in one operation, it's considered as two different client. So my solution is:

1. to do the auth on server-side and when the auth is done, save a radom token for this user.
2. Send on the JSP page an hidden input field with the pair (iduser,token)
3. On JS client, i include in each request a pair (iduser,token) from the html page.
4. On my google endpoints, i check for each request the validity of the token then do what to do...

PS: the token can be with a validity period or any other fields